# Unable to get file list from external storage directory in Droid

Tags: android

I am trying to access external storage in Android.

I want to push some images so that I can use this in my application.

The code I am using as follows:

```
File directory = new File(String.valueOf(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
 + File.separator + AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM);
```

*PS: PHOTO_ALBUM is defined as "papu"*

It returns `/storage/emulated/0/papu`

I cannot see this path exists through DDMS, file explorer but this condition is true;

```
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
}
```

Anyways, I assumed that it is reading from mnt/shell/emulated/0/papu

When I try to get all files through

```
File[] listFiles1 = directory.listFiles();
```

It does not return any files at all.

How can I push files when I don't this folder in the DDMS explorer ?

Here is how the DDMS looks like:

[image]

And my code is:

```
File directory = new File(String.valueOf(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
                + File.separator + AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM);

        // check for directory
        if (directory.isDirectory()) {

            File[] listFiles1 = directory.listFiles();
```

Comment: Have you made sure to have http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the android manifest file?

Comment: suger! it was indeed missing (READ_Ex.. as I was porting tis project to new folder !!!! Fixed!